# Postgresql - sequences bigger than bigint

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-12

PostgreSQL sequences (`CREATE SEQUENCE`) are limited to `bigint` (which is usually big enough). But in my case I need a bigger sequence. The table will not have this much records, it will be cleaned over time, but the numbers must never be reused. As I am planning this to be used for at least 20 years, there is the need to go bigger than `bigint`.

I am using `NUMERIC(35)`.

How can I achieve this with less locking as possible?

Is creating two sequences and summing them a good idea?

Comment: Maybe [UUID](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-uuid.html) with custom sequence function?

Comment: If you use 10000 values per second 24/7 without any pause, it will take you 29.247.120 years to burn through a bigint sequence - if you allow negative values as well, then it's twice as long

Comment: "Is creating two sequences and summing them a good idea?" Probably not. But instead you could have a "version" which is a tiny integer starting at 1, and then the sequence value. When the sequence overflow, you increment the version by 1, so you go to 2, and start the sequence over. Of course various queries will need to take this into account but it is easy in PostgreSQL as you can do (versionA, sequenceA) < (versionB, sequenceB)

Answer (score 3):

As pointed out by @a_horse_with_no_name, bigint is good enought. I think 29 million years is reasonable (hehe).

The math checks. Should have done it before.